# Parse error on ": " (STRING) GraphQL error on react Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, graphql

I was trying to create a board item on the monday.com website using graphQL and it worked fine when I checked it on graphQL playground and postman software. but when i tried to call it in react using axios it shows this error message in console.

```
{message: 'Parse error on ": " (STRING) at [6, 37]', locations: Array(1)}
```

Here is my function,

```
  const CreateItem = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        url: endpoint,
        method: 'post',
        headers: headers,
        data: {
          "query": `mutation ($item_name: String!,$board_id: Int!,$group_id: String!,$column_values:String!) {
            create_item(
              item_name: $item_name,
              board_id: $board_id,
              group_id: $group_id,
              column_values: "{"value": "$column_values"}"
              create_labels_if_missing: true
            ) { id }
          }`,
          variables: {
            item_name: String("Testing Item"),
            board_id: parseInt(3551570930),
            group_id: String("topics"),
            column_values: String("Api Testing"),
          },
        }
      });

      if (response.data) {
        console.log(response.data);
      } else if (response.errors) {
        console.log(response.errors);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

is this issue occurring when I'm parsing the values? ( I'm new to this environment)

Comment: Hello. Are you sure it is legal to interpolate variables inside the value of a field? I believe that's what you're doing in column_values: "{"value": "$column_values"}". Furthermore, I think that if the double quotes are part of the string literal maybe they should be escaped in some manner, and that may be why the parser is complaining.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do with `column_values: "{"value": "$column_values"}"` but that is not valid gql or even javascript.